# What is the best alternative to work one afternoon in Brussels during a trip?

Tags: planning, internet, belgium, brussels

I have a friend traveling through/visiting Belgium. He needs to work one afternoon in Brussels before his flight.

He is looking for something cheap. Preferably free. With Internet. Since it's winter working outside is not an option.

The airport could be an option, but he is afraid the Internet might fail and the hour rate is expensive.

What's the best option to work one afternoon in Brussels in a warm place with Internet?

Any sugestion is welcome but I think he prefers more informal spaces like a cafe or so.

Comment: Starbucks or the like?

Comment: @MeNoTalk It's a possibility but I don't know if they have internet and if you can access other services than the Web.

Comment: @pnuts "other services" in the Internet and not only web (FTP, etc)

Comment: @MeNoTalk something like that coul be.

Answer (score 3):

(Note: I am not connected to this company either as a client or employee, I simply found them via Google)

It appears that [Regus](http://www.regus.com/day-office/belgium/brussels?q=Brussels,Belgium) has some space available in Brussels for rent by the hour. There were several listed as Day Offices, Fully Equipped. Most were listed at either ~15 Euro or ~25 Euro.

Comment: If you're going down the Regus route, then their [Business Lounges](http://www.regus.co.uk/products/business-lounges/) are likely to be a better bet - much cheaper and aimed at the roadwarrier wanting somewhere to get some work done for a few hours to a day

Answer (score 3):

There are a few coworking spaces for rent on [Sharedesk](https://www.sharedesk.net/search?city=Brussels,%20Belgium&wsTypeGroup=work) for around 20EUR for the whole day. It may be possible to work at a cafe or the airport, but these spaces are more reliable in terms of comfort for getting work done and internet connection as well.